# Listbox Populated From Worksheet, Can't Find Original Value

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform, populate

I was able to populate my listbox using a range of values from my worksheet. Now I want to populate the cell next to the value selected from the listbox, but it cannot seem to find the original value that is selected from the listbox.

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For j = 2 To LastRow
    If Cells(j, 2).Value = cmbStage.Value Then
        For k = 2 To LastRow
            If Cells(k, 3).Value = lstJobCard.Value Then
                Cells(k, 4).Value = lstJobCard.Value & ": " & txtNote.Value
            End If
        Next k
    End If
Next j
Unload Me

End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't figure out why you have a double for loop?  The inner loop will ignore the results out of the outer loop and just place the value next to every found instance of `lstJobCard` in column 3.

Comment: @tigetavatar i am iterating through two different columns. The first for loop will loop through column B and find the value from the combo box. The second for loop will look for where the cell matches the list box, given that the combobox is already found. If it matches both, I want it to output the note textbox. This was my initial thinking. It is currently not finding the cell where both are equal (even though it is there).

Comment: don't have a second loop then, just add an `And` condition to your if statement: `If Cells(j, 2).Value = cmbStage.Value And Cells(j, 3).Value = lstJobCard.Value Then`

Comment: @tigeravatar i tried that and it still didn't work. Excel is saying that none of the cells match my lstJobCard.Value, even though that list box was populated from the range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Rather than saying if that cell value was equal to lstJobCard.Value, I had to say "Like". For example

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For j = 2 To LastRow
    If Cells(j, 2).Value = cmbStage.Value Then
        For k = 2 To LastRow
            If Cells(k, 3).Value Like lstJobCard.Value Then
                Cells(k, 4).Value = lstJobCard.Value & ": " & txtNote.Value
            End If
        Next k
    End If
Next j
Unload Me

End Sub
```

Still not sure why, but it works now.